# use of fms server

Tags: php, flash, flash-media-server

is an fms server necessary while using flash media player?
how does one do http streaming using flash player?

Comment: sorry "flash media player" is a bit confusing, did you mean "flash player" or is it actually video player coded in flash named "flash media player" - if yes can you specify a link to its home page ?

Answer (score 2):

By FMS I guess you mean **RTMP Stream** (against **progressive 'stream'**) ?

An on-demand RTMP stream will serve you exactly the portions of requested content whereas a progressive stream will download the whole file into the clients browser cache (the same way it does for an image). Thanks to that you can jump to a position in the video even though the preceding part hasn't been loaded, this is a great feature if you are dealing with longer videos.

A progressive video is easier to set up as you just have to deploy it on a simple HTTP server, this can also be a bad point as you may overload the HTTP bandwidth whilst the RTMP streaming service can be hosted on a dedicated server specialized in streaming so you can achieve an optimal service. FMS 3.5 provides dynamic streaming meaning the stream will get adapted depending on the users bandwidth.

**Basically :**

If the video is a mayor concern for your website, and/or you want to provide an enhanced user experience in terms of quality and response you should go for RTMP streaming (FMS, Red5, etc.). Otherwise don't complicate things, just upload it to your HTTP server and download it progressively.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/). Here are [some tutorials.](http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [Mammoth](http://mammoth-project.org/) server (previously named OpenFMS).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/)

[Here](http://askmeflash.com/article/10/comparison-wowza-vs-fms-vs-red5) a comparison between FMS, wowza and red5

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/stream-ondemand-flash-and-ios.html) about HTTP streaming (HDS) to Flash and iOS.